# formula QUERY, where AN contains results that start from NSE:MOL, NSE:MOLDTKPAC miss match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In B3 QUERY, where AN contains results that start from NSE:MOL, G1 is the same name and words that start from NSE:MOLDTKPAC So the result is a mismatch because I got two entries in b3 and b4, which means **b3 should not be there**. The issue is that only the starting words are the same. Is there any solution?   **[Test File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MmzMA5DG1aOFTe_OcdUua3TMHdYinepfweK6UTT7cEU/edit?usp=sharing)**

one more thing match words also not worked out coz i have take all which is like
NSE:MMTC:F0004
NSE:MMTC:F0002
NSE:MMTC:F000 manymore

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try replacing this part of the formula*

```js
AN contains '"&B1&"'
```

with

```js
AN matches '"&B1&"\b'
```

- *`\b` establishes a **word_boudary check** to the right end*

Comment: Wow Great Work Really thank you so much, i will try on main sheets and update you thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following argument: And Not AN Contains '"&G1&"' , and the complete formula is: =QUERY('Buy&Sell'!$AM$4:$AS,"select AM,AO,AR,AS where AN contains '"&B1&"' AND NOT AN contains '"&G1&"' order by AM desc, AO asc limit 9",0)

Comment: it is just a test file but G1 contains Name will be changing as per price-wise order every time  so this formula is useful if it fixed the cell but these B1, G1, and L1 contain WORDS always change, can you please alter solution, thank you for your time and helping me